# How to solve T(n)=2T(√n)+(loglogn)^2?

Tags: recurrence-relation, recursion, master-theorem

Trying to solve the recurrence, but no clue how to deal with the (loglogn)^2 part

Comment: Substitute $n = 2^{2^k}$ in the entire expression. Can you solve the recurrence in terms of $k$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Assuming base $2$ logarithms, we can write

$$\begin{align}T(65536)&=2T(256)+4^2\\&=4T(16)+2\cdot3^2+4^2\\&=8T(4)+4\cdot2^2+2\cdot3^2+4^2\\&=16T(2)+8\cdot1^2+4\cdot2^2+2\cdot3^2+4^2\end{align}$$

Hence, generalizing the pattern, you see the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\lg(\lg(n))}{k^22^{\lg(\lg(n))-k}}=\lg(n)\sum_{k=1}^{\lg(\lg(n))}{k^22^{-k}}$$ appear, as well as a term $$\lg(n)T(2).$$